# Как сделать глобальную обработку ошибок в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, axios, promise

Есть приложение. Если пользователь слишком долго бездействовал, его сессия завершается. После этого пользователь может нажимать что угодно, но у приложения никакой реакции, а я хочу это исправить. Я сделал вот такую функцию:

```
const notAuthAC = () => ({type: NOT_AUTH})

export const handleForbiddenError = (response, dispatch) => {
    if (response.status === 403) {
        dispatch(notAuthAC());
    }
}
```

Я вызываю её во всех санках и передаю в неё response и dispatch, имеющиеся у санки. Функция проверяет статус ответа и, если возвращается 403 ошибка, диспатчит нужный action creator, и это отбрасывает пользователя на страницу аутентификации.

Вот только ошибки так легко не обрабатываются оказывается, надо делать блок try...catch. На мой взгляд это очень муторно, делать обработку ошибок в каждой санке нет никакого желания.

Есть ли какая-то возможность глобально отлавливать в одном месте все ошибки? Кстати, я использую axios.

Comment: Вам дорога в `axios interceptors`, как раз занимается тем, что вы пытаетесь обрабатывать. К сожалению, не могу дать пример на React, только на Vue/Nuxt реализовывал.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar а вообще в принципе требование к try...catch это чисто из-за axios или в ванильном js тоже ошибка выбрасывается? я просто в js не силён

Comment: Это уже отслеживает Axios, если ответ положительный (2xx), то отработает, иначе выбрасывает исключение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как для запросов я использовал `axios`, то я сделал специальный перехватчик. Для запросов я использую готовый объект `axios`:

```
const apiRequester = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    withCredentials: true
});
```

Перехватчик устанавливается таким образом:

```
apiRequester.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    // логика при успешном запросе
}, error => {
    // логика при ошибке
});
```

В дальнейшем, когда я использую объект `apiRequester` для запросов, то всегда вызывается данный перехватчик. Например, при помощи него я установил логику редиректа на страницу логина, когда у пользователя истекла сессия или он просто не аутентифицирован:

```
apiRequester.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    return response;
}, error => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
        setNotAuth();
        return Promise.reject(error);
    } else {
        throw error;
    }
});
```